# JCarousellite not auto-scrolling - no clue what's wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoscroll, jcarousellite

I've got a website (http://firewoodracks.com/test/index.html) where I want the small product slider to auto-scroll.  It's using JCarousellite and I've edited it a thousand times but the auto-scroll simply won't work.

Here's the code, copied directly from the JCarousellite website (full script located here:http://firewoodracks.com/test/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js)

```
(function($) {                                      

    // Compliant with jquery.noConflict()
$.fn.jCarouselLite = function(o) {
    o = $.extend({
        btnPrev: null,
        btnNext: null,
        btnGo: null,
        mouseWheel: false,
        auto: 800,

        speed: 500,
        easing: null,

        vertical: false,
        circular: true,
        visible: 3,
        start: 0,
        scroll: 4,

        beforeStart: null,
        afterEnd: null
    }, o || {});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Am I editing the wrong script?  Help!

Answer (score 0):

If you check on their website download page, you will see it says:

Version 1.0.1 - (Uncompressed) (Minified) (Packed) - **Jquery 1.2 Compatible**

However, on your website, you are using jQuery **1.3.2** (http://firewoodracks.com/test/js/jquery.min.js).

This might be the problem.

I'd suggest either using a different plugin that supports a more recent version of jQuery, or try swapping out your jQuery for the version it supports to see if that works.

Comment: I swapped out the jquery and it actually broke the whole slider.  Is this maybe working on another javascript file that's not the jcarousellite?

Comment: That's very odd, because if you look at their demo page source code you can see which jQuery version is being used.